# Please any help to Compute the following limit

Tags: analysis

Let $-1<a_0<1$ and define recursively $a_n=((1+a_{n-1})/2)^{(1/2)}$. If $A_n=4^n(1-a_n)$ compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} A_n$.

I have showed that ${a_n}$ converges to $1$ and that $A_n$ is increasing. But i can't to show that $A_n$ is bounded or something that allow to concluide the convergence of $A_n$. Please any help or suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let $a_0 = \cos \theta\;$
then
$$
a_1 = \sqrt{\frac{1+\cos \theta}2} = \cos \frac{\theta}2
$$
so
$$
a_n = \cos \frac{\theta}{2^n}
$$
and 
$$
1-a_n =2 \sin^2 \frac{\theta}{2^{n+1}}
$$
perhaps you can take this a little further...

Comment: I tried to use this and I used the fundamental limit sinx/x , concluding that the limit is (theta)^2 divided by 2, am I right??

Comment: think that's right ;-), though in the terms in which the problem was stated it may be more appropriate to write your answer as $ \frac12 (\cos^{-1} a_0)^2$

Comment: Yes it is more convenient , so theta is well defined. Thanks for your help.